# Error handling in shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, trap

I wrote a shell script `run_script.sh`, which includes a step which creates an empty file `run_script.lck`. Everytime the shell script was called by the cronjob, it will check for the existence of `run_script.lck`. If the lock is presence, it indicates that `run_script.sh` is already running and hasn't finished yet. The `run_script.lck` file will be deleted in the end of the program.

The trouble is to remove the lock file when the shell script crashed and before it exits.

I wrote a line like this:

```
trap "rm -f run_script.lck" EXIT
```

But it will remove the lock file in an undesired condition like this:

I execute `run_script.sh` in shell A, and it is running, the lock file was created. Then I execute it again in shell B, and it said that the script is already running and the script will be aborted. However, because the trap received an EXIT signal including the signal from shell B, which is exiting an aborted script, then it removes the lock file. And the script in shell A is still running, but the lock was deleted and anyone can call another `run_script.sh` again while there is already one script running.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To illustrate Ignacio's answer (use following protocol: first check if lockfile exists and then install the trap), you can solve the problem like this:

```
$ cat test2.sh
if [ -f run_script.lck ]; then
  echo Script $0 already running
  exit 1
fi
trap "rm -f run_script.lck" EXIT
# rest of the script ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Check for presence of the lock *before* setting the trap.

Comment: Finally we still need to set the trap and it will exit.

Answer (score 4):

On way is set the trap on errors and let `sh` abort the script in case of errors (`set -e`). For example

```
$ cat test.sh
set -e
trap "echo foo" ERR
if [ $# == 1 ]; then
  exit 0
fi
false
$ bash test.sh
foo
$ bash test.sh 1
$
```

(where `$#` is the number of arguments)

In your script you just have to make sure that you execute your trap command when the script runs successfully (i.e. no crash happens, e.g. at the end of your normal program-flow).

`set -e` means that each exit status unequal `0` ends the execution of the script. Similar to that, with `set -u` every (probably accidental) use of an undefined variable ends the execution.

Thus, transferring this idea to the original use case, a solution could look like this:

```
$ cat test.sh
set -e
trap "rm -f run_script.lck" ERR
if [ -f run_script.lck ]; then
  echo Script $0 is already running
  exit 1
fi
#
# do all the work ...
#
# no error until now
rm -f run_script.lck
```

Comment: what does the if statement do?

Comment: @gunbuster363, it checks if one argument is supplied. In your use case you would check the existence of the lock-file. I updated the answer with another example.